# datetime difference from two schemas

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, schema

I'm trying to select all records from `schemaOne`.`abc` where `abc`.`TIMESTAMP` is 3 weeks or less before `schemaTwo`.`xyz`.`TIMESTAMP`

So if:

`schemaOne`.`abc`.`TIMESTAMP` = `2016-03-08`

And:

`schemaTwo`.`xyz`.`TIMESTAMP` = `2016-03-01`

Then `schemaOne`.`abc`.`TIMESTAMP` should be fetched, but if:

`schemaTwo`.`xyz`.`TIMESTAMP` = `2012-03-01`

Then `schemaOne`.`abc`.`TIMESTAMP` should not be fetched.

My attempt at it:

```
SELECT ID FROM schemaOne.abc WHERE `TIMESTAMP` > (SELECT `TIMESTAMP` FROM schemaTwo.xyz) - INTERVAL 3 WEEK;
```

Returns the error:

```
Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I suspect that I may have to do a `UNION` or represent queries `AS` `A` and `B` to pass parameters between them but I'm no MySQL expert so I'm pretty much stuck here. Perhaps there's an easier way of doing this?

Comment: How do you relate these two tables?

Comment: `abc` has `ID` and `xyz` has `abc_ID`

Comment: You want results based on the matching IDs only, right?

Comment: You sir, are a legend.

Comment: No sir I am not. Thanks for the compliment though. :) @Hooli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `schemaOne.abc.ID` is referred by `schemaTwo.xyz.abc_ID` then the following query might be the one you expected.

```
SELECT 
schemaOne.abc.ID
FROM schemaOne.abc
INNER JOIN schemaTwo.xyz ON schemaOne.abc.ID = schemaTwo.xyz.abc_ID 
WHERE schemaOne.abc.`TIMESTAMP` > (schemaTwo.xyz.`TIMESTAMP` - INTERVAL 3 WEEK);
```